# ScrollView with Sticky view goes under status bar

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to achieve this effect for sticky view to not go under StatusBar and to fill out above space with background color when it sticks:

[image]

Currently I'm using `stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}` and it's working fine but not with SafeAreaView. What I'm thinking is to add initially transparent View above sticky view with height of StatusBar and then when it sticks, to add white background to it. But I'm having troubles how to catch when it sticks. I tried looking for some callbacks or anything, can't find anything.

What I have now:

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I got it. If anybody needs to achieve similar thing, get a ref from that sticky View, on ScrollView add onScroll and in that callback measure View and check y/pageY if it's 0 or any other value you need and store something like `isSticky: boolean` in state.